# Unable to boot LiveCD on an Atom N2600

Tags: boot, 13.10, system-installation, live-cd

Recently purchased a [JetWay MiniITX PC](http://www.jetway.com.tw/jw/barebone_view.asp?productid=946&proname=JBC362F36-2600-B%20/%20JBC362F36W-2600-B) which contains an Intel Cedar N2600 Atom Processor.

I'm attempting to boot off a Live USB with 13.10 64 bit (I've also tried 12.04 32 bit).

It starts booting, then stops outputting to the monitor, causing it to go into standby.

I've tried with nomodeset, no difference.

Comment: Have you tried to press F6 at boot time and add one, two or these 3 commands: acpi=off noapic noalpic ?

Comment: Have you tried to disable the UEFI in the BIOS?

Comment: @giggsey What method did you use to create the Live USB? I've found that they are not all created equal. I too have had difficulty with Atom based systems and Live USB.

Comment: As far as I know the Atom cpu's are ARM cpu's, so 64-bit will not work on them. Sitting on one atm, my OS is a 32-bit ubuntu 14.04. So I think you should try a 32-bit 13.10 instead of 64-bit.

Comment: @desgua Tried all those options, no luck

Comment: @konqui Unable to find it in BIOS.

Comment: @ElderGeek Using the recommended USB burner from window. The USB is good, because I've installed other PCs with it

Comment: @DanJohansen The processor is 64bit. I've also tried 32 bit 12.04 (LTS), and that didn't work.

Comment: Everyone: I managed to get CentOS 6.5 installed using a USB CD Drive. However, trying Parted Magic via the same CD drive failed. So not really sure...

Comment: @giggsey Have you used it to install other PCs since it failed on the Jetway? As long as it's a FAT filesystem and the boot record isn't corrupted I would expect it to work.

Comment: @Dan Johansen I have successfully booted the Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit on the  Acer D270 (upgraded to 2GB RAM) netbook which has the same Intel N2600 Atom processor.

Comment: Have you run a memtest? CentOS requires less RAM to install than Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to really figure out what the issue is. Can you please try the ubuntu boot again, however remove 'splash' from the end of your kernel arguments. Then post what the last thing the livecd attempts doing prior to it just locking up. With that we should have more of an idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: @darkdragn As it goes far too quick to read, I've uploaded a video from my phone: http://rowvid.com/?v=T3h_LDPyP-w&t=22.23&s=0.25 - That link is the last frame showing output. The one before says something about "video: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel"

Comment: @darkdragn Just tried 14.04 amd64 desktop booting from USB. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new live USB using startup disk creator from ubuntu 12.04 if available.

Start with a new USB stick or erase an existing one first and **format it with a FAT filesystem**

Choose the ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Choose your newly formatted USB stick

Choose when starting up from this disk Documents and settings will be discarded to avoid creating a persistence file.

Continue making the stick entering the root password when prompted to insure the boot loader is installed.

Eject the stick when complete using the appropriate button on the nautilus side panel.

Safely remove the stick by powering it down using the disk utility.

Insert the stick in an available USB port. Check your system manual for the key to choose boot device (Often F12)

Choose the USB stick you just created from the menu.

The system should boot. If it doesn't, contact Jetway for further assistance. There own product page indicates that you must be able to boot from a DOS partition To upgrade the BIOS so this should do the trick.

Be patient. The screen may blank and then return.

Full disclosure: I tested this process on an Acer D270 netbook which has the same processor. YMMV

Insure you have at least 2GB of available RAM for installing  ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

---

You appear to be having a problem with the video drivers based on the video from your phone in your comment. Lubuntu or Xubuntu might be a better choice for the limited capabilities of the cederview graphics.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211217

Answer (score -1):

Use actual version of Knoppix. I encountered similar problem with RescueCD (Gentoo based) on the same hardware platform (Atom N2600). Knoppix starts as live system without any problems. Next maintenance, eg. disk partitioning & installation to disk can be carried out.